# Faking a method results in "incompatible method and shim" exception

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, shim

I am working with Shims and Fakes in VS 2013 Premium. When Shimming out a method for all instances, I get the error "incompatible method and shim" at runtime. Compilation provides no indication of any errors.

The code in question:

```
ShimViewModelBase.AllInstances.GetQueryCriteriaFromUriNavigationContext = (T, C) => { return new List<QueryCriteria>(); };
```

I appreciate any insight that can be provided.

As requested, this is the method definition I am trying to Shim out.

```
 public List<QueryCriteria> GetQueryCriteriaFromUri(NavigationContext inContext);
```

Full Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: incompatible method and shim
```

Stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.AttachDetour(Object optionalReceiver, MethodBase method, Delegate detourDelegate)
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.SetShimMethod(Delegate optionalStub, Object optionalReceiver, MethodBase method)
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.SetShim(Delegate optionalStub, Type receiverType, Object optionalReceiver, String name, ShimBinding flags, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.SetShimPublicInstance(Delegate optionalStub, Type receiverType, Object optionalReceiver, String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Infrastructure.Fakes.ShimViewModelBase.AllInstances.set_GetQueryCriteriaFromUriNavigationContext(Func`3 value)
   at MaterialTracking.UI.Module.Tests.NotificationsListViewModelTests.OnNavigatedToTest() in c:\CodeCoverage\Material Tracking\MaterialTracking.UI.UnitTests\Views\NotificationsListView\NotificationsListViewModelTests.cs:line 65
```

I have also tried this

```
  ShimViewModelBase sBaseViewModel = new ShimViewModelBase((ViewModelBase)notificationsListViewModel);
            sBaseViewModel.GetQueryCriteriaFromUriNavigationContext = (T) => { return new List<QueryCriteria>(); };
```

Comment: I edited the provided code to include what was requested

Comment: Can you share more about the `ViewModelBase` class? Is it an abstract class? Internal class? is it from a framework? Is it a custom class for your project? Do you have a minimal project that shows the problem?

Comment: ViewModelBase is part of a framework that was written at my company. It is an Abstract Class. It has a base class as well as implementing a few interfaces.
I do not have a minimal project as I have not be able to reproduce it in another project without using the framework.

Comment: I have the same problem. I suspect it's something with the inheritance tree that's causing the issues. Have you tried setting the shim on an implementation instead if the abstract base class?

Comment: The method is not available for Shimming on the implementation class as it uses the implementation defined in the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this issue because there is a mismatch between product dll and corresponding fakes dll. Its very much possible that in your product code the signature of function "public List GetQueryCriteriaFromUri(NavigationContext inContext)" has been changed but the corresponding fakes dll is still old. Create the fakes dll corresponding to updated product dll and try to run the test. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It looks like at runtime, it is pulling a different version of the class from the GAC while it uses the local dll with the updated class during compile.